# Create OpenGL ES texture with two float16 values (beginner)

Tags: opengl-es

I need to create a texture for an OpenGL ES 2.0 application with the following specs:

- Each pixel has two components (lets call them r and g in the fragment shader).
- Each pixel component is a 16 bit float.
- That means every pixel in the texture has 4 bytes (2 bytes / 16 bit for each component).
- The fragment shader should be able to sample the texture as 2 float16 components.
- All formats must be supported on OpenGL ES 2.0 and as efficient as possible.

How would the appropriate glTexImage2D call look?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Neither floating point textures nor floating point render targets are supported in OpenGL ES 2.x. The short answer is therefore "you can't do what you are trying to do", at least not natively.

You can emulate higher precision by packing pairs of values into a RGBA8 texture or render target, e.g. the pair of `RG` values is one value, and `BA` is the other, but you'll have to pack/unpack the component 8-bit unorms yourself in shader code. This is quite a common solution in deferred rendering G-buffers for example, but can be relatively expensive on some of the lower-end mobile GPU parts (given it's basically just overhead, rather than useful rendering).